# Is there a standard name for (non-square) matrices with orthonormal columns?

Tags: linear-algebra, na.numerical-analysis, terminology, orthogonal-matrices

One encounters often in numerics non-square matrices with orthonormal columns, i.e., $U\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, with $m > n$, such that $U^TU=I$ (but, clearly, $UU^T \neq I$).

Is there a name for these matrices?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

***Orthonormal $\boldsymbol n$-frames*** :  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiefel_manifold.

Added: This terminology of Hirzebruch ([1966](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=202713)), Steenrod ([1951](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=39258)) translates the ***$\boldsymbol n$-Systeme*** of Stiefel ([1936](//zbmath.org/?q=an:0014.41601)), ***$\boldsymbol n$-podes***, ***$\boldsymbol n$-pèdes*** or ***multipèdes*** of Einstein ([1931](//zbmath.org/?q=an:57.1199.04)), Waelsch ([1907](//zbmath.org/?q=an:38.0482.01)), ***$\boldsymbol n$-Beine*** or ***Vielbeine*** of Hirzebruch ([1956](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=82174)), [Einstein](http://echo.mpiwg-berlin.mpg.de/MPIWG:YP5DFQU1) ([1928](//zbmath.org/?q=an:54.0942.04)), Blaschke ([1920](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:47.0694.02)), or [Waelsch](//books.google.com/books?id=lqEKAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA246&dq=Vielbein+bein) ([1906](//zbmath.org/?q=an:37.0113.01)).

Answer (score 3):

Francois Ziegler has already provided a very relevant answer.

Let me point out three further relevant things:

**1.** While the OP is not expressly interested in matrices with integer entries, a very relevant article nevertheless is [W.
 Plesken: *Solving $XX^{\mathrm{tr}}=A$ Over the Integers.* Linear Algebra and its Applications. Volumes 226–228, September–October 1995, Pages 331-344](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002437959500156L#). Therein, in is in particular proved (let $A=I$ and $X=U^{\mathrm{t}}$) that in the context of the OP

$U^{\mathrm{t}}U = I\quad$ ${}\quad$ if and only if${}\qquad\qquad$  $(U U^{\mathrm{t}})^2 = U U^{\mathrm{t}}$ $\quad$and$\quad$ $\mathrm{tr}( UU^{\mathrm{t}})=n$

$\color{white}{( U^{\mathrm{t}}U = I )}{}\quad$ if and only if${}\qquad\qquad$ $UU^{\mathrm{t}}$ is idempotent and has its trace equal to its rank

$\color{white}{( U^{\mathrm{t}}U = I )}{}\quad $ if and only if${}\qquad\qquad$ $UU^{\mathrm{t}}$ is idempotent,

where the first equivalence holds by Proposition 2.2 in loc. cit., the penultimate holds by a mere reformulation of the first-mentioned equivalence (note that the OP's hypotheses imply that $U U^{\mathrm{t}}$ has rank $n$), and the last step being a widely-known, not-quite-obvious fact from linear algebra (every idempotent matrix has its trace equal to its rank).

So we have shown:

> The matrices of the OP are precisely those $U\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ for which $UU^T$ is an idempotent in the matrix ring $\mathrm{Mat}(m\times n;\mathbb{R})$.

**2.** Moreover, in the context defined by the OP we have:

> If the OP's hypotheses are satisfied, then *the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse of $U$ equals the transpose of $U$*. Conversely, if $U$ is a real matrix whose Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse equals its transpose, then the sum of the squares of the rank-sized minors equals $1$. <sup>1</sup>

Proof of 2. By the usual formula,

> $U^+ =  \biggl(\overline{U}^{\mathrm{t}}\cdot U\biggr)^{-1}\cdot \overline{U}^{\mathrm{t}}\qquad\qquad$ (0).

Sufficiency: If the OP's hypotheses are satisfied, then $\overline{U}^{\mathrm{t}}\cdot U = \mathrm{Id}$ and $\overline{U}^{\mathrm{t}} = U^{\mathrm{t}}$, so (0) implies $U^+=U^{\mathrm{t}}$.

Necessity: Suppose conversely that $U^+=U^{\mathrm{t}}$. Then (0) implies that $U^{\mathrm{t}} = (U^{\mathrm{t}}U) U^{\mathrm{t}}$. 
This implies $U^{\mathrm{t}}U = ((U^{\mathrm{t}}U) U^{\mathrm{t}})\cdot(U(U^{\mathrm{t}}U))$  $=$ (by associativity) $=$ $( U^{\mathrm{t}}U)^3$, hence, applying the homomorphism $\det\colon \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}\to\mathbb{R}$ it follows that, abbreviating $d:=\mathrm{det}(U^{\mathrm{t}}U)$, we have $d = d^3$. Since the OP's hypotheses imply that $U^{\mathrm{t}}U\in\mathbb{R}^n$ has full rank $n$, we know that $d\neq 0$, and hence it follows that $1=d^2$, and hence $d\in\{-1,+1\}$; for further reference,

> $\det(U^{\mathrm{t}}U)\in\{-1,1\}\qquad\qquad (1)$.

By the [Cauchy-Binet-theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Binet_formula), it follows from (1) that (in particular since sums of squares of real numbers are non-negative)

$$1 =  \sum_{S:\quad\textsf{$n$-element subsets of $m$}} \det( U|_{S\times n})^2 $$

The completes the proof of **2.**

<sup>1</sup> <sub>This is not a "name", yet may lead the OP to useful relevant literature.</sub>

Comment: aren't the only integer orthogonal matrices signed permutations?

Comment: @Turbo: yes, but Plesken's Proposition 2.2 is valid (and explicitly stated) for *any* matrix $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times k}$, the specific *title* of the paper notwithstanding.